# (Snowflake) cumulative sum of revenue divided by cumulative count of users

Tags: sql, t-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an Orders table. Relevant columns are accountid, orderdate (timestamp) and grossamount. On a year-month basis (yyyy-mm) I need to calculate the sum total grossamount of all orders and divide this number by the total count of (distinct) account ids.

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT
     TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', orderdate::date), 'yyyy-mm') AS year_month,
     SUM(grossamount) / COUNT(DISTINCT accountid)
FROM orders
GROUP BY year_month
```

But this obviously calculates the sum of grossamount and the count of accountids for each year_month, whereas for each year_month I need these values to be from the beginning of the data up until the end of that year_month.

Assume also that no month will be blank i.e. every one has at least one order.

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
(SUM(grossamount) / COUNT(DISTINCT accountid)) OVER (PARTITION BY year_month ORDER BY year_month)
```

work for you?